# How do I create a global custom error page for ASP.NET MVC3?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I brand new to ASP.NET MVC3.  How would I create a global custom error page for MVC3?  The general idea is when an exception is thrown it would show a generic message to the user and it would log the exception to a database for developers to investigate later.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Here is what I ended up doing in global.asax.cs:

```
    protected void Application_Error()
    {
        var exception = Server.GetLastError();

        Log.Error("Exception", exception);

        var httpException = exception as HttpException;
        Response.Clear();
        Server.ClearError();
        var routeData = new RouteData();
        routeData.Values["controller"] = "Error";
        routeData.Values["action"] = "General";
        routeData.Values["exception"] = exception;
        Response.StatusCode = 500;
        if (httpException != null)
        {
            Response.StatusCode = httpException.GetHttpCode();
            switch (Response.StatusCode)
            {
                case 403:
                    routeData.Values["action"] = "Http403";
                    break;
                case 404:
                    routeData.Values["action"] = "Http404";
                    break;
            }
        }

        IController errorsController = new ErrorController();
        var rc = new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(Context), routeData);
        errorsController.Execute(rc);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Global.asax` file implement the `Application_Error` method:

```
    protected void Application_Error() { 
        HttpContext ctx = HttpContext.Current; 
        var error = ctx.Server.GetLastError();
        ctx.Response.Clear(); 
        ctx.Response.End(); 
    }
```

Following up on Maess' comment:

Read this: [Error Handling in asp.net mvc 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5995776/error-handling-in-asp-net-mvc-3)

Comment: Good point, but that is only going to handle unhanded exceptions or HTTP errors like 404, 500 etc.

Comment: @Maess: I've added some more specific info

Answer (score 1):

What I've done in my project is I created a `BaseController` and overridden the `OnException` event as below,

```
protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
{
    // do some logging using log4net or signal to ELMAH
    filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
    var exModel = new HandleErrorInfo(filterContext.Exception,  
                  filterContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString(), 
                  filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString());
    View("Error", exModel).ExecuteResult(ControllerContext);
}
```

Also I removed the `HandleError` action filter registered in the `Global.asax.cs`.

Note: You should have a view with name `Error` in shared folder.

Update: To extract the error information from the `Error` view you have to bind the `Error` view to the model `HandleErrorInfo`.

```
@model System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorInfo
```

Then you can easily access the exception anywhere in the view as

```
@Model.Exception
```

Comment: That is really interesting.  How do I extract the exception out of the view so I can display it?

Answer (score 0):

Create a view called Error and add it to your Views\Shared folder.  Then in your catch blocks, after you have logged the error, redirect the action to the error view.  If you want to display a sophisticated message create an Error model and pass it to the view, or put the information into the ViewBag.

For information on unhandled exceptions and HTTP errors see Ropstah's post.