# AJAX call returning Interal Server Error in ASP.NET MV3 project

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm new with and using ASP.NET, MVC3 and AJAX.

I try to call a method in my controller with an AJAX call, but I receive an Internal Server Error.

Here's my Javascript method:

```
function DeleteItem(id) {
  var answer = confirm("Are you sure ?")
  if(answer) {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '/Item/Delete',
      data: id,
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function (data) {
        alert('Function called');
      },
      error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert(xhr.status);
        alert(thrownError);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

and here's my method in my Controller:

```
public ActionResult Delete(int idItem) {
  Item.Delete(idItem); //delete my item
  return RedirectToAction("Index", "Item");
}
```

The Javascript method is called, but when I answer "Yes, I'm sure I want to delete", I get an Internal Server Error and I am not sure why. What causes the server error?

Comment: `Item.Delete(idItem);` should be `Item.DeleteItem(idItem);` dont you think?

Comment: Consider ways to handle errors in your MVC actions:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5995776/error-handling-in-asp-net-mvc-3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that the reason you are getting an internal server is because the name of the int that you are passing in does not match the int that you are expecting in your controller.  As a result, idItem is most likely null which is causing your internal server error when going to delete.

Change the data to match

```
function DeleteItem(id) {
    var answer = confirm("Are you sure ?")
    if (answer) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/Item/Delete',
            data: { idItem: id},
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                alert('Function called');
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    alert(xhr.status);
                    alert(thrownError);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: [HttpPost] was missing and I didn't match id and idItem in the "data" fiel of the ajax call

Thank you very much guys !

Comment: @AlexB glad it worked for you!!

Answer (score 0):

Your ActionResult method does not have the [HttpPost] attribute.  Your Ajax call is of type 'POST'.

Comment: Why this will prevent calling this action with a GET request, it will not cause an error.

Comment: Yes, but HttpPost is an action filter.  It's not NEEDED for a POST to work.  It prevents calling the Action with GET, PUT, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need to serialize the `id` you are passing to action to JSON format. And you also need to decorate your action method with `[HttpPost]` attribute so that it accepts POST verbs.